# Delete all k8s pods created by a cronjob

Tags: cron, kubernetes, jobs

I have a cronjob that runs every 10 minutes. So every 10 minutes, a new pod is created. After a day, I have a lot of completed pods (not jobs, just one cronjob exists). Is there way to automatically get rid of them?

Comment: See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52390

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a work for labels.

Use them on your `CronJob` and delete completed pods using a `selector` (`-l` flag).

For example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: periodic-batch-job
            is-cron: "true"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: cron
            image: your_image
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Delete all cron-labeled pods with:

```
kubect delete pod -l is-cron
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for my situation, my pods where not fully terminating as I was running one container with the actual job, another with cloud sql proxy, and cloud sql proxy was preventing the pod from completing successfully.

The fix was to kill the proxy process after 30 seconds (my jobs typically take couple of seconds). Then once the job completes, successfulJobsHistoryLimit on the cronjob kicks in and keeps (by default) only 3 last pods.

```
    - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        command: ["sh", "-c"]
        args:
        - /cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myinstance=tcp:5432 -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json & pid=$! && (sleep 30 && kill -9 $pid 2>/dev/null)
```